# Standard definition of smoothness on an arbitrary subset

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I know two definitions of smoothness on an arbitrary set.
Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, $A\subseteq M$ be an arbitrary subset of $M$ and $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

1. $f$ is smooth iff there is an open set $U$, $A\subseteq U$ and a smooth function $\bar{f}:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f = \bar{f}$ on $A$.
2. $f$ is smooth iff for every $p\in A$ there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $p$ and a smooth function $\bar{f}:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\bar{f}=f$ on $U\cap A$.

Which is standard one?

Comment: What do you mean by standard? These definitions appear equivalent to me.

Comment: I don't know that proof but even if manifold need not be Hausdorff and second countable, are these equivalent?

Comment: Well, 1 clearly implies 2 by choosing the $U$ and $\bar{f}$ from 1 for every $p \in A$. It seems like you could use a partitions of unity sort of idea to construct the $U$ in 1 from some of the $U_p$ and $\bar{f}_p$ in 2, but I haven't worked through the details to check if that works for non-Hausdorff spaces.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The standard definition for me, is defined with local parametrizations. Let $M$ be an $n$-manifold and $f: A \subset M \to \mathbb{R}$. Let $(\phi,U)$ and $(\psi, V)$ be local charts on $M$ and $\mathbb{R}$. Then we say $f$ is smooth if $\psi \circ \tilde{f} \circ \phi^{-1}: \phi(U) \subset\mathbb{R}^n \to \psi(V) \subset \mathbb{R}$ is smooth. Here we take $x \in A$ and $U$ is an open set about $x$ for which $\tilde{f}|_A = f$. In other words $f$ is smooth, if there is an extension where this composition is smooth and the extension has the other property given.

Edit: The local chart on $\mathbb{R}$ can be dropped since we know the coordinate system there and so we only need $\tilde{f} \circ \phi^{-1}$ to be smooth.